How to filter out the http.response_in field to get the response packet using Pyshark
As shown in the picture, the request packet is 2291, the response packet is 2293.
The response_in field not found by packet.The dir method and debugging didn't work out.
captures = pyshark.FileCapture(file)
for packet in captures:
    packet.http.response_in  # Error


